# void* to Object^ in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, wrapper, void-pointers

I am working on wrapping a large number of .h and .lib files from native C++ to Managed C++ for eventual use as a referenced .dll in C#.

Some of the native C++ functions have a return type of void*.  I am not sure how to handle this when I pass back the value to my calling code. For instance: if a C# app calls my dll wrapper, what do I return from the native call:

```
void* start(ThreadFunc,void *, unsigned *);
```

I am currently attempting to box the return in a generic System::Object^ with no luck.  This is the call in the wrapper:

```
m_NativeThread->start(cb, 
        GCHandle::ToIntPtr(GCHandle::Alloc(o)).ToPointer(),
        static_cast<unsigned int*>(GCHandle::ToIntPtr(GCHandle::Alloc(u)).ToPointer())));
```

Can anyone offer a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make it an IntPtr? What do you expect the client to do with the void*?

Comment: I wouldn't know what they would do with the void * honestly.  I guess it would help if I knew why it is declared with a void* in the first plalce...What is the purpose of a void *?  Why/When would I use it?

Comment: A void-pointer is a pointer to an unknown type, kind-of like a reference to System.Object in .NET, but without the associated runtime type info (that is, you can't interrogate the reference for its type). 

I phrased my question badly, I really meant: "What does the start() function expect that you use its return value for?" Because if it's never used, you can just discard it. If it's used as a handle for e.g. terminating the thread, I'd expose it as an IntPtr.

Answer (score 5):

If your managed code needs to see the data in the void*:

> You can't cast a void* to unmanaged
>   memory to a managed object reference.
>   To turn this into managed memory,
>   you'd have to use Marshal.Copy() or
>   Marshal.PtrToStructure(). That will of
>   course only work if you know the type
>   of the data that the void* points to.
>   [source](http://bytes.com/groups/net-vc/649329-void-pointer-managed-object-type)

If your managed code doesn't need to see the data in the void*:

> Store it in an IntPtr if your
>   managed code doesn't need to see what
>   it is and just passes it back into the
>   unmanaged code later on.
>   [source](http://www.tech-archive.net/pdf/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.vc/2007-05/msg00195.pdf)