# CLI/C++: void* to System::Object

Tags: pointers, c++-cli, command-line-interface

This is a similar question to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154929/void-to-object-in-c-cli), which I have been unable to use to solve my problem. I have included some code here, which will hopefully help someone to bring home the message that the other posting was getting at.

I want to write a CLI/C++ method that can take a void pointer as a parameter and return the managed object (whose type I know) that it points to. I have a managed struct:

```
public ref struct ManagedStruct { double a; double b;};
```

The method I am trying to write, which takes a void pointer to the managed struct as a parameter and returns the struct.

```
ManagedStruct^ VoidPointerToObject(void* data)
{   
    Object^ result = Marshal::PtrToStructure(IntPtr(data), Object::typeid);
    return (ManagedStruct^)result;
}
```

The method is called here:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{   
    // The instance of the  managed type is created:
    ManagedStruct^ myData = gcnew ManagedStruct();
    myData->a = 1;  myData->b = 2;      

    // Suppose there was a void pointer that pointed to this managed struct
    void* voidPtr = &myData;

    //A method to return the original struct from the void pointer
    Object^ result = VoidPointerToObject(voidPtr);  
    return 0;
}
```

It crashes in the `VoidPointerToObject` method on calling `PtrToStructure` , with the error: **The specified structure must be blittable or have layout information**

I know this is an odd thing to do, but it is a situation I have encountered a few times, especially when unmanaged code makes a callback to managed code and passes a void* as a parameter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(original explanation below)

**If you need to pass a managed handle as a `void*` through native code, you should use**

```
void* voidPtr = GCHandle::ToIntPtr(GCHandle::Alloc(o)).ToPointer();

// ...

GCHandle h = GCHandle::FromIntPtr(IntPtr(voidPtr));
Object^ result = h.Target;
h.Free();
```

(or use the C++/CLI helper class `gcroot`)

---

`Marshal::PtrToStructure` works on *value types*.

In C++/CLI, that means `value class` or `value struct`.  You are using `ref struct`, which is a *reference type* despite use of the keyword `struct`.

A related problem:

```
void* voidPtr = &myData;
```

doesn't point to the object, it points to the handle.

In order to create a native pointer to data on the managed heap, you need to use pinning.  For this reason, conversion between `void*` and `Object^` isn't as useful as first glance suggests.

Comment: Additionally, `Object::typeid` is useless when calling `Marshal::PtrToStructure`; one is supposed to pass the type of the structure they're actually marshaling, not the type of `System::Object`.

Comment: @ildjarn Thanks for the help. I tried to pass `ManagedStruct::typeid` instead of the type of `System::Object`, but I get a _cannot convert from 'System::Object ^' to 'ManagedStruct' error_, so had been using the solution I posted as a workaround. Any idea what this might be?

Comment: @Rory : That error indicates you were trying something like `(ManagedStruct)Marshal::PtrToStructure(IntPtr(data), ManagedStruct::typeid)`, which would be correct if `ManagedStruct` were a value type (as Ben noted it must be). However, because your `ManagedStruct` is a reference type, that cast is nonsensical -- `(ManagedStruct^)Marshal::PtrToStructure(IntPtr(data), ManagedStruct::typeid)` would compile, but then fail at runtime for the reasons Ben listed.

Comment: @Ben Voigt @ildjarn Thank you both very much. Changed `ManagedStruct` from reference to value struct and removed all the `^` handles. Used pinning to create native pointer to data on managed heap, with `pin_ptr<ManagedStruct> pinnedPtr = &myData;` and then `void* voidPtr = pinnedPtr;`. It works fine now

Comment: @Rory: No, it only looks like it's working fine.  But when `pinnedPtr` goes out of scope, `voidPtr` will be dangling.

Comment: @Rory: I just reread your final sentence.  You don't want a pointer to the managed object, you want a pointer value that can be used to recover the managed object, and will keep it from being collected by the garbage collector.  That's what `GCHandle` is for.  See edit.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Thanks for catching that. Managed object now remains in the same location on the heap even when it appears to be out of scope

Comment: @Ben Voigt `GCHandle::Free(h);` from your answer gave me a compile error, though. Using VS2010 with .NET framework 4.0 and regular /clr support. I changed this to `h.Free()` and it appears to do the right thing, allowing the garbage collector to free up the space on the managed heap.

Comment: @Rory: You're right, it's a non-static member function.  No clue why `Alloc` is static, `ToIntPtr` is static, but `Free` is non-static.  You're doing the right thing, I'll fix the code.  Sorry about that.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I've been looking for this for days, using VS2008 .NET calling a function from an older C++ DLL which required a context returned to the callback function which then should add things to the context form.

Comment: It may be worth adding that GCHandle is not in the default namespace. In order for that code to compile, you need this: `using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;`

Comment: @endavid: It seems like a good idea to add that line to the question, which is already using the `Marshal` class from that namespace.