# Dereferencing a void* to a basic type in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

How can you dereference the value that a void* points to in C++/CLI, particularly, I would like to assign it to an int.

```
int Callback(void* returnValue)
{
   int lookUpValue = *returnValue; // How to do this??

   if(lookUpValue==1)
     DoSomething();
   if(lookUpValue==2)
     DoSomethingElse();

    return CALLBACK_SUCCESS; // Defined elsewhere.
}
```

I tried:

```
{
    GCHandle h = GCHandle::FromIntPtr(IntPtr(voidPtr));
    Object^ result = h.Target;
    lookUpValue = (int)result;
    h.Free();
}
```

from example:
[CLI/C++: void* to System::Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903208/cli-c-void-to-systemobject)

but found that in some cases the h.Target was undefined and I would get a crash. So don't think I have been able to do this correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just dereference a `void*` directly because the resulting type wouldn't be known. You have to cast the `void*` to `int*` before dereferencing it:

```
int lookUpValue = *static_cast<int*>(returnValue);
```

The related post you've found doesn't apply since an `int` isn't an object managed on the GC heap, so you can't get a GC handle to it.